# What determines how long the task switcher stays up?

Tags: task-management, recents-screen

Samsung Note II running OctOS M, but I have seen this phenomenon with multiple phones and versions of Android going back to 2.x

When you bring up the task switcher in Android, sometimes it stays up until you're done, somtimes it goes back to the home screen while you are swiping/closing apps.

What determines how long you stay in the task switcher?  What other apps or settings impact that functionality?

Comment: "goes back to the home screen while you are swiping/closing apps" - never seen this. I'm also a long-time Android user dating back to 2.x. Could you have accidentally tapped the empty area outside?

Comment: No, the phenomenon happens after swiping as I am about to swipe again, sometimes causing me to launch a new app. Its possible my capicitance is different and affects the phone differently, but that's pretty esoteric...

Comment: That does sound like some problem in interacting with the touch panel. You should possibly turn on "pointer location" in Developer options to try catching any ghost touches.